# A problem with Temporal, should it be classified as a bug?

Tags: qgis, temporal-controller

[image: Originalfields before truncating to lat,lon,date]I have previously used Temporal for animations with no problem but when I tried a new animation today with "Single field with date/time" the input below didn't show down arrow to select field, double L & R clicking made no difference.[image: Grab of dialogue box].   A previously working animation has stopped working and shows same behaviour when temporal is selected.

The file in question had different columns for date and time.  So I modified file to first have date only column and second a merged date/time column.  Exactly the same result ie field selection arrow had no effect.  restarting QGIS between each attempt.  I suspect that QGIS temporal has become corrupted and will need to reload QGIS.

Unfortunately that is not the answer I removed/reinstalled QGIS but the original Temporal problem remains.  Any ideas?
The only way that this problem could arise is that
Temporal was modified on the lines of `if field type not Date then ignore` which would explain why a previously working animation failed.

I have tried the field calculator but the "Update field" is greyed out.
[image]
The only data required for an animation is lat, lon & date (or date/time) the other fields are not required.  So the solution is to use simple csv file in conjunction with csvt file.

Comment: Which version of qgis? Which platform: win10?

Comment: On your screenshot, everything looks all right, down arrow to select field appears as it should. What exactly is the problem? Did you try to restart QGIS, maybe you machine as well? Does the problem persist?

Comment: If there are no fields formatted as date/datetime, you can't select any fields and the down arrow will do nothing as you don't have anything to select

Comment: The problem is nothing changes when the down arrow is clicked. I have tried restarting QGIS and machine many times.  There is a date/time field in the file in question.  As I stated before when a previously working animation is loaded it shows the same problem.

Comment: QGIS is Hanover 3.16.1 on Ububtu 20.04.  The same QGIS version is working fine on Win 10 Surface Book.

Comment: So the problem is on Ubuntu only, not on Windows? So that means that's a specific for QGIS on Ubuntu - as I don't work on Ubuntu, I can't reproduce.

Comment: Same fault on Win10 now, thought it might be that date format was wrong initially so changed to correct format but still got same problem.

Comment: Can you make a sample of your data available to see if the problem can be reproduced on other machines?

Comment: Did you make sure that the field that stores your date is really formatted as datetime field type and not as string? See layer properties, tab fields: what kind of field type is set for the field there? See: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43jLg.png)

Comment: I tried to edit to add a truncated file but only allows images.  However the initial file is set to date type, I re checked but properties, tab fields IS set to Text. I presume that must be the problem but why would QGIS set it to text?  I couldn't change the type, is it possible once loaded?  I will try to load again and see if there is anything I missed on add layer dialogue.

Comment: How did you load the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116688/discussion-between-vic-and-babel).

Comment: I just updated my answer, plese see there for details about loading data. In my case, I had no trouble at all to load the data and setting temporal, even without creating a csvt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that QGIS does not recognize dates if they are stored in a field formatted as string. In this case, QGIS temporal is not able to recognize a date-type data field and thus, you can't select anything. That explains the behaviour in your case what is just as expected in this case. It seems your date was converted to a string fieldtype when you imported it.
See Anita Graser's blog for a solution: https://anitagraser.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/

But you don't have to re-import everything. You can convert the existing date field by creating a new field using field calculator and converting the string to date type. Use `to_date` or `to_datetime` expressions. For more detailed advise, plese include a sample (even if screenshot) of your date field.

---

Update: load data

I uploaded three files so that you cant test if everything works as it does on my machine: `data.csv` - the sample data you provided as delimited text. `data.gpkg` - the same converted to a Geopackage. temporal_test.qgz - a test project with both of these files as layers and activated temporal setting for the csv layer. You find the data here: https://drive.switch.ch/index.php/s/EE58pZKVfGKm8Ei

So please try of all the following steps work for you:

I copied the first 4 rows of the data you provided in your screenshot in an exel sheet and saved it as csv utf-8 coded. I imported that file to QGIS 3.16.0 on Win 10; `Data Source Manager / Add Delimited Text Layer` and activated `Detect field types` - see screenshot:

[image]

Than I accessed `Layer Properties / Tab Temporal`. There, I could easily select the `Date` field that contains the timestamp. I did not encounter the problem you describe:

[image]

The Date field of the imported csv points layer is clearly recognized as being of date type without any manual changes:

[image]

Comment: The only way I could get this to work was by reducing the file to 3 fields, lat,lon and date with the csvt file = "Real","Real","Date" both files have to be the only files in their folder, if they are with other files QGIS ignores the csvt file.  I still don't understand why a file that previously worked perfectly in QGIS Temporal suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Did you try to convert the field with the field calculator? If you could add at least one row of your original data (be it as screenshot) to your question, it would be easier to know what we discuss about. It's quite difficult to guess "in the dark" without seeing your data what's going on. Maybe something went wrong when you imported your data as csv - be very carfeful about separator characters. If they are not set accordingly, your data might get messed up.

Comment: By the way: if you copy a few cells of your csv in exel, you can paste it to your question as well, dont need to make screenshot

Comment: It does work correctly with the files you provided.  I did originally forget to convert date format from dd mm yyyy to yyyy mm dd when I first loaded the file.  I then converted date but it still had the same problem.  I think if I had restarted QGIS that might have saved a lot of frustration.  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: You're welcome. Consider accepting this answer if it solved your problem

Comment: Accepted but is there a way of doing that formally?

Comment: Yes, there is a formal way to do that and to signal that the problem has been solved: just hit the check mark next to the question on the left side: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpe2V.png
The tour says: The person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". Accepting doesn't mean it's the best answer, it just means that it worked for the person who asked - see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour