# Deleting and reinstalling QGIS

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

I have a problem with QGIS as here [Previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380108/a-problem-with-temporal-should-it-be-classified-as-a-bug?noredirect=1#comment621543_380108).  I think QGIS Temporal is corrupted and the only way to correct is to uninstall and reinstall QGIS (QGIS 3.16.1 Ubuntu 20.04). However if I try this via Ubuntu Software I get the error

> Unable to remove "QGIS Desktop: The following packages have unmet
> dependencies

but no packages are listed.  Is there a way to remove QGIS or reinstall/repair via Terminal please?
It would be nice if people were intent on answering questions rather than nitpicking wording

Comment: Please review this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/254768/29431

Comment: Thank you, that removed QGIS.  I then reinstalled but the original problem with Temporal is recurring after removing/reinstalling.

Comment: Sorry if I offended you with my edits, you can easily roll back whenever you want. I just simply wanted to improve the quality of your question =)

Comment: It's just that Stack Exchange  often seems to be more concerned about HOW a question is worded than with the actual question.